# Why are there different ways of building projection matrices?

Tags: directx, projection, perspective

[Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation page says that this method uses the following formula to build a perspective projection matrix.

```
[w, 0, 0, 0]
[0, h, 0, 0]
[0, 0, zFar/(zFar - zNear), 1]
[0, 0, -zNear * zFar / (zFar - zNear), 0]
```

where

```
h = cot(fovY / 2)
w = h * aspectRatio
```

DirectXMath's **DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH** uses the same formula but with a difference. It calculates **w** as **w = h / aspectRatio** therefore creates a different matrix.

There is a difference between orthogonal projection matrix building too.

Why are there such differences or am i missing something?

Comment: What makes you think that XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH uses w = h / aspectRatio?  That would be exactly opposite of the way aspect ratio is universally defined as w/h, which implies w = h * aspectRatio.  And in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixperspectivefovlh.aspx) it explicitly says the aspect ratio is "X:Y" i.e. w/h.

Comment: I stepped in the function call when debugging. The line is `float Width = Height / AspectHByW;`. The code is in file **DirectXMathMatrix.inl** and can be found under **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um** directory at Win8 machines.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  The parameter is even called `AspectHByW`, which is in contravention of both what the docs say and the way everyone else in the world defines aspect ratio.  WTF.

Comment: To give a conclusion to anybody reading this: `AspectHByW` is incorrectly named, you should pass `W/H` and *not* `H/W`. Confirmed by the devs here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/issues/25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because there are many ways to compute the projection of objects in a 3D scene onto a 2D plane. That's why you have perspective versus orthographic projections (and various flavors thereof, such as off-center projections), and that's why you can use slightly different formulae to compute the projection transformation.

Sometimes the differences are semantic in nature (such as in the case of perspective versus orthographic). Sometimes they are purely conventional in nature. Sometimes they are due to known quantities or characteristics of the inputs the system.

It's sort of similar to how you can represent your vectors as 4x1 or 1x4 matrices, and that consequently has a impact on whether you multiply your vectors on the right or the left of your transformation matrices.

Comment: Hmm, i see. So both are correct and used for creating different projections. But i don't understand why would anyone want to use **w = h * aspectRatio** one. Because when i render a square it gets stretched horizontally and looks like a rectangle therefore unrealistic.

Comment: Perhaps that method expects a different computation for aspect ratio.

Comment: yes, you are right! i tried 1:1 aspect ratio and it looked as expected. thank you.